# jQuery custom validation rule question

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a random math generator and a .get command that sets the value from the returned data. For instance the input #Captcha would get it's value as such:

```
$.get('PHP/random.php',
    function(data) {
    $("#Captcha").val(data);
});
```

If the returned data was something like 2 + 5 how would you create a rule that turns the value into two integers, strips out the "+" and then combines the two integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. But if you just to add the two (or more) numbers together this should work:

```
var test = "2+5";
var numbers = test.split('+');
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    result += parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/L8VMH/

Comment: Since the numbers will be randomly generated, not always 2 + 5 would something like this work: var test = $("#Captcha").val(); ?

Comment: Should work fine. I've added a jsfiddle example that does just that.

Comment: awesome, really appreciate it.